# My react component written in typescript does not accept children

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is the error TypeScript (Version 3.9.2) gives me:

`Error:(24, 21) TS2559: Type '{ children: Element; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<ClassAttributes<ComponentClass<Pick<MyComponentPropsType, ...>, any> & WithRouterStatics<typeof MyComponent>> & Pick<...>, "ref" | "key">'.`

Code of the component:

```
interface MyComponentPropsType{
    location: any,
    match: any,
    history: any
}

class MyComponent extends Component<MyComponentPropsType>{
  // do some stuff
  render(){
    return <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(MyComponent));
```

Usage of said component somewhere else:

```
<MyComponent><AnotherComponent></MyComponent>
```

The weird thing is, the error pops up only sometimes.
There are times typescript compiles perfectly and sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really stupid error, that will waste hours or days and I stumbled upon a solution by accident.
So this is what happens:

withRouter or connect or both (I am too lazy to look it up) will memoize the component. 
Which creates a component of the type "NamedExoticComponent".
According to this [discussion](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/33602) NamedExoticComponents do not have children in their props.
Thus the solution is simple:
Change the MyComponentPropsType to

```
interface MyComponentPropsType{
    location: any,
    match: any,
    history: any,
    children: React.ReactNode
}
```

I wasted hours on this and feel really stupid now, but I hope it will save you some time and nerves.

Comment: this worked for me

// Typescript raises issues if I export HOC directly to AdminProtectedRoutes
// workaround is to create a variable and export that variable
let companyComponent:any = connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Company);
export default companyComponent;